# when is a local namespace to be destructed in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

```
def f():
   L = []
   for i in range(5):
       def n():
           return i
       L.append(n)
   return L

L = f()
print(L[0]())
print(L[1]())
print(L[2]())
print(L[3]())
print(L[4]())
```

the output of the above codes is

```
4
4
4
4
4
```

my questions is: after `L=f()`, is the local namespace of `f` destructed? if so, how is the `i` in function `n` associated with `i` in the namespace? if not, when is a local namespace to be destructed?

Comment: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/closure. Same idea as what you're doing

Comment: @MadPhysicist thank you so much for commenting. I also wonder why the output is 4 4 4 4 4 instead of 0 1 2 3 4.

Comment: I've added an answer that clarifies

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a number of "local" namespaces in a function call that make things like your example behave. Specifically, there are three types of variables in a function:

1. Local: used in the function only. Values may be returned, but binding to local name is destroyed when function exits. `L` in `f` is an example.
2. Cell: used in function and some nested scope as well. These names are recreated whenever the function is called, but persist afterwards as a closure in the nested scope. `i` in `f` is an example.
3. Free: not defined in the function. These are divided into two types, global and non-global. Global variables do not get placed in a closure. Instead they are accessed through the `__globals__` attribute of the function. Non-globals persist in the cells of the `__closure__` attribute when the enclosing namespace is gone. `i` in `n` is a nonlocal free variable.
4. There are also builtin names, but we don't talk about those.

When you call `f`, `L` and `i` are local names. When `f` ends, the object created for `L` is passed out of the function, but the binding to the local name `L` is destroyed. However, the binding to `i` is not destroyed because it is a cell variable. The binding lives in the `__closure__` attribute of each element of `L`.

If you look at `L[0].__closure__`, you will find `i` in a cell there. `L[1].__closure__` will have a reference to the same cell, also with `i` in it. The cell is the same because it comes from the same invocation of `f`.

When you call `n` via the elements of `L`, the last value of `i` is printed because that's what the cell was bound to when `f` exited.

You could get different behavior by binding the value of `i` as a local variable in `n`. For example:

```
def n(i=i):
    print(i)
```

Now `i` in `f` becomes local because it's no longer used as a nonlocal in `n`. In `n`, `i` is now a local variable that gets its value from the default argument. Default arguments are bound when the function object is created, so will reference the local value of `i` at the time the list elements are made. This contrasts with free variables, which are looked up in the closure when the function runs. The output of this version will be

```
0
1
2
3
4
```